# memory leak in sqlite3 in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, sqlite

Its location based application and application crash after 5-6
  Minutes. When I run the app using performance tools, leaks, I keep
  finding that all of my classes leak memory.  i am calling this
  function second by second. Please properly close my database or
  sqlite3. Thanks.

```
 - (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {



            for (int i=0; i<[arrayAlerts count]; i++) {
                   Msg=[DatabaseManager GetSelectedMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select text_msg  from TextMsgTemplate  where msg_id=%d",ObjAlertInfo.msgID]];
        }

    in Databasemanger

    +(NSString *)GetSelectedMessage:(NSString *)SQL
    {

        NSString *msg;//=[[[NSString alloc]init] autorelease];
        msg=nil;
        sqlite3_stmt *dataset=nil; 
        dataset=[DatabaseManager getMessages:SQL];

        while ((sqlite3_step(dataset)==SQLITE_ROW) ) {
            msg=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(dataset, 0)];

        } 

        sqlite3_finalize(dataset);

        dataset = nil;
       return msg;

    }


    +(sqlite3_stmt *)getMessages:(NSString *)SQL
    {

        sqlite3_stmt *dataset=nil;

        sqlite3_stmt *finaldataset=nil;

        if (sqlite3_open([[self getdatabasePath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK ) {


            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [SQL UTF8String], -1, &dataset, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
            {
                NSLog(@"error get message");
                return nil;

            }else{
                finaldataset= dataset;  

            }

       }

        sqlite3_close(database);

        return finaldataset;

    }
```

Comment: And where does Instruments tell you the leak is?

Comment: memory increase second by second in instruments.. showing in Blue color.. NOT IN RED

Comment: And the stack trace (right hand pane) told you what?

Comment: "no stack trace available in this block" , i think problem in allocation. All Allocation is showing 25.15 Mb in one minute. when i change ** Msg=[DatabaseManager GetSelectedMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select text_msg  from TextMsgTemplate  where msg_id=%d",ObjAlertInfo.msgID]]; ** to ** Msg=@"Hello"; **    .... then no extra memory allocation and app running perfectly..

Comment: I'm confused why `getMessages` closes the database, but then `GetSelectedMessage` proceeds to call `sqlite3_step` and `sqlite3_finalize`. If I'm reading that right, I'm surprised it works at all. Generally you open, prepare, step, finalize, and close. Notably, finalize is supposed to freeing memory resources, but don't know what it would do if the database was already closed.

Comment: As an aside, have you run your code through the static analyzer (shift-command-B), too?

Comment: Thanks Robert Ryan for Hint.. now its working fine.. Thanks alot :)